# Boy transported to mystic land, fights evil, future self helps him as a wizard

Tags: story-identification

This was a book I read in the early part of the 2000's. I can't remember title or author and it's driving me mad.

The protagonist is a youngish man transported to a mystical land and is taught by a wizard, maybe named Merlin. He has a sword (Excalibur?) that he uses to cleave the goblin king in two from head straight down, and is instructed to clean the blade by driving it into the stone and pulling it out.

I believe there is a scene where the good guys are making a last stand on an island or a shore fighting off evil creatures coming at them from the water by using fire of some kind.

In the end he is brought back to his time and it is revealed that the wizard was really himself from the future.

My memory of this book is fairly limited, but the scene with the goblin king is still very vivid. I believe anyone who is familiar with the book should recognize it from that scene.

Comment: Some googling turns up [The Wizard of Time](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Wizard_of_Time_Book_1.html?id=VzZeXwAACAAJ&hl=en) as a possible match

Comment: Nope, too historic, not enough fantasy. I don't think he was apprenticing as a mage either, more like a king/general.

Comment: @gntskn I will add that you should provide that as an answer instead of merely a comment. Even if it is not correct, you can give details about it that might help someone else looking for an answer.